# Flutter - Disable navigation InAppWebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm new to Flutter, and I want to put a web view between other widgets and I'm using the InAppWebView flutter in order to do it, but I want to prevent the user to navigate to other pages when he clicks on a button inside the web view. Do I have to write some native code for iOS and Android to prevent the navigation?

Thanks

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098276/11315821

Answer (score 12):

Since you are using `InAppWebView` package you can intercept each URL the Webview would navigate to before it is actually navigate and then make a decision of whether to navigate or not using the callback `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` like the following:

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
    // You can access the URL like this
    final url = navigationAction.request.url.toString();

    if (condition) {
        // This one means do not navigate
        return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
    }

    // This one means navigate
    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
},
```

**Note**: To use the callback `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, you have to enable it in the `initialOptions` of the webview like the following because the default is `false`:

```
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Good, InAppWebViewOptions step is important.

Comment: this does not seem to work in flutter web. have you tried it in the web version?

Comment: On Updated version, It is not working on mobile side as well. Can you share the package version as well that you used.

Answer (score 6):

something like that:

```
InAppWebView(
....
 shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
  final uri = navigationAction.request.url!;
  if(whitenAvigationHosts.contains(uri.host)){
    return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
  }
  return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
})
```

Comment: this does not seem to work in flutter web. have you tried it in the web version? –

Answer (score 2):

For disable navigate user to another page you can use **onPageCommitVisible** call back to determine the user is click on url that redirect to another one, so just call goBack inside it

```
 InAppWebView(
        onPageCommitVisible: (con,uri){
          print("url ${uri.toString()}");
          con.goBack();
        },

      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

### **Disable navigation `InAppWebView`:-**

we have `onUpdateVisitedHistory` property in `Inappwebview` widget.Using this `onUpdateVisitedHistory` property we can listen url changes in the `Inappwebview` widget.So disable navigation we can use `webcontroller.goback()` method.

widget code:

```
InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
                _loadHtmlFromAssets();
              },
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                if (url!.host.contains("google.com")) {
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  //You can do anything
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("yahoo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen3()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("duckduckgo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
                  );
                }
              })
```

[image]

Here we skipping loading the search engine and jump to other widget

nb: if we did'nt add `webcontroller.goback()`.it will load site and move to the widget .if we back pressed it will show webpage.

**sampleCode:**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  WebViewController? _controller;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;
  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            webViewController?.goBack();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: InAppWebView(
              key: webViewKey,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
                _loadHtmlFromAssets();
              },
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                if (url!.host.contains("google.com")) {
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  //You can do anything
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("yahoo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen3()),
                  );
                  //Prevent that url works
                  return;
                } else if (url.host.contains("duckduckgo.com")) {
                  //You can do anything
                  webViewController?.goBack();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen2()),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ));
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() {
    var fileText =
        "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title> <style> .rotate { transform: rotate(1700deg) ; } .rotate2 { transform: rotate(90deg) ; } .bg { background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover; height: 50vh; width: 50vh; } body { margin:0; overflow:hidden; } </style> </head> "
        "<!-- Start your code here --> <ul> <li> <a href ='http://duckduckgo.com/' /><p> duckduckgo.com</a> </li>  <li> <a href='http://www.google.com'>google.com </a> </li>    <li> <a href='http://www.yahoo.com/'> yahoo.com </a> </li></ul> </html>";
    // return Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
    //         mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
    //     .toString();
    webViewController!.loadUrl(
        urlRequest: URLRequest(
            url: new Uri.dataFromString(fileText, mimeType: 'text/html')));

    // _controller?.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileText,
    //         mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
    //     .toString());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("Screen 1 google.com"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: MaterialApp(
        home: Container(
          child: Text("Screen 2 yahoo.com"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Text("Screen 3 duck.com"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### **Disable navigation in `Webview` Widget:**

We can use `navigationDelegate` to monitor url changes in `webview`.`NavigationDecision.prevent` will block jump to website

```
WebView(
      // initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller = webViewController;
        _loadHtmlFromAssets();
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.contains("google.com")) {
          //You can do anything
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
          );
          //Prevent that url works
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        } else if (request.url.contains("yahoo.com")) {
          //You can do anything
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen1()),
          );
          //Prevent that url works
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        } else if (request.url.contains("duckduckgo.com")) {
          //You can do anything
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Screen3()),
          );
          //Prevent that url works
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        //Any other url works
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent navigation in webview through navigation delegate property like following:

```
WebView(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
        initialUrl: _currentURL,
        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
          _controller = controller;
          return _controller;
        },
        onPageFinished: (url) {
          if (url.contains(ConstUtils.course)) {
            updateProfile();
          }
        },
        navigationDelegate: (navigation) => NavigationDecision.prevent,
        onWebResourceError: (error) {
          NavigationUtils(context).popCurrentPage();
        },
        onPageStarted: (url) {
          
        },
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
```

Comment: It worked on android but in iOS, the web page is not even loaded.

Comment: I am a native android developer, don't know much about iOS. But I think it's configuration issue, not issue of this package. check other sources this issue has been resolved.

Comment: The question is asking about the package `flutter_inappwebview` not `webview_flutter`

Answer (score 0):

For android Prevent that URL works you can use                   `webViewController?.goBack();` (But not work on ios device)

You can use
`webViewController?.stopLoading();` (work on both device ios & android)
For Prevent that URL works

If above solution make blank screen in android the use simple ifelse

```dart
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  webViewController?.stopLoading();
} else {
  webViewController?.goBack();
}
```