# How to disable navigation away from initial URL in Flutter Webview

Tags: flutter, webview, navigation

I have a Flutter app that loads a web site into a WebView widget.

Is there any way to lock that webview to the initial website? I don't want the user to be able to navigate away from this page.

Comment: what package you are using to show webview in flutter?

Answer (score 3):

In a `StatefullWidget` you can put this line of code:
The `navigationDelegate` plays the key role in this scenario.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Web View'),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.engenesisBlue,
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          print(request.url);
          setState(() => counter++);

          if (counter == 1) {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

The web view will refuse to navigate twice. Therefore you cannot navigate once the page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like:

```
  onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
    if (navigation.url != 'https://flutter.dev') {
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
```

or if you want to allow navigation in domain only:

```
  onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
     if (!navigation.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev')) {
      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    }
    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  late final WebViewController controller;
  String url = 'https://flutter.dev';

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onNavigationRequest: (navigation) {
            if (navigation.url != url) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```